# How to combine a Convention-based Customization with AutoFixture's [AutoData] attribute?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

I am using [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture)'s [`[AutoData]`](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/08/AutoDataTheorieswithAutoFixture/) attribute to provide some unit tests (NUnit) with an instance of a POCO. For example:

```
[Test, AutoData]
public void Create_NameIsNull_ThrowsException(MyPOCO myPOCO) {..}
```

I've recently added a new string property to my POCO that must always contain a properly formed URL.

Naturally, `[AutoData]` is not aware of this requirement and generates the usual GUID-based string value for this property. This causes my tests to fail (because of some [Data Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx) based validation that I have in place).

I've followed @ploeh's advice and written a [Convention-based Customization](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/19/Convention-basedCustomizationswithAutoFixture/) for AutoFixture that specifically generates a properly formatted URL string for this new property of mine. It is a class called `UrlSpecimenBuilder` that implements `ISpecimenProvider`.

My question is, how can I combine my new `ISpecimenProvider` with `[AutoData]`?

I don't want to have to go `fixture.Customizations.Add(new UrlSpecimenBuilder());` in each one of my unit test. I'm looking for a single test fixture setup step that will do the same thing.

Comment: As I also mentioned in our [Twitter conversation](https://twitter.com/urig/status/760085204971163649), the appropriate reaction would be to change the type of the property from `string` to `Uri`, thus avoiding [Primitive Obsession](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/25/DesignSmellPrimitiveObsession). In that conversation, you also hinted at this not being applicable in this case, but since that's not apparent to a casual reader of this post, I've added this comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should define your own version of the `AutoDataAttribute` and apply all the customizations you need. If the customizations are relevant for all the tests, it might be called `DefaultAutoData`:

```
[Test, DefaultAutoData]
public void Create_NameIsNull_ThrowsException(MyPOCO myPOCO) {..}

internal class DefaultAutoDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
  public DefaultAutoDataAttribute()
    : base(new Fixture().Customizations.Add(new UrlSpecimenBuilder()))
  {
  }
}
```

See [this Mark Seemann post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/08/AutoDataTheorieswithAutoFixture/) for details.

Answer (score 4):

You can also override the [`CustomizeAttribute`](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture.NUnit3/CustomizeAttribute.cs) to arrive at a syntax like

```
[Test, AutoData]
public void Create_NameIsNull_ThrowsException(
  [MyPOCOWithValidUrl] MyPOCO myPOCO) 
{..}
```

[Some real world examples](https://github.com/SkillsFundingAgency/das-reservations/tree/master/src/SFA.DAS.Reservations.Web.UnitTests/Customisations)